# Can I convert a SVG stored as XML in SQL Server (only) to a different image type?

Tags: sql-server, svg, xml-parsing, crystal-reports

I'm trying to take a SVG image stored in XML code in an `NVARCHAR` column in SQL Server and display it in Crystal Reports. Crystal Reports does not allow SVG natively so is there a way to work around this limitation?

Comment: Not without SQLCLR. Quite why you are storing XML in `nvarchar` or why you are storing bytes *inside* that XML I'm sure you know yourself, but it doesn't sound very efficient

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Crystal UFL (User Function Library) to add a function within Crystal so that the ***Graphic Location*** expression can use that function to:
a) materialize the image in the database into a file and
b) on-the-fly, replace the dummy image with the new one.

See list of 3rd-party UFLs [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#ufl).